# How to use wildcards in nodejs child_process.exec

Tags: node.js

Why does this not work? How to do it right?

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

exec("ls data/tile_0_{0..63}.jpg", function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout); 
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr)}
);

// stdout: 
// stderr: ls: cannot access data/tile_0_{0..63}.jpg: No such file or directory
```

In bash terminal this lists all files like `tile_0_0.jpg, tile_0_1.jpg, etc.`

This executed from node works as expected but does not do the thing I want.

```
ls data/tile_61_[0-9].jpg
```

Please help me ...

I'm using Linux Mint 14.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do

```
var _ = require('underscore'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  files = fs.readdirSync('data');

var filtered = _.filter(files, function(filename){
  return filename.indexOf('tile_0_') == 0;
});
```